# Удаление дублей в массиве

Tags: php

есть первый массив:

```
Array
(
[овощи] => Array
    (
        [0] => огурец
    )
[фрукты] => Array
    (
        [0] => апельсин
        [1] => мандарин
    )
[рыба] => Array
    (
        [0] => налим
        [1] => сазан
        [2] => щука
        [3] => плотва
    )
)
```

и второй массив:

```
Array
(
[овощи] => Array
    (
        [0] => помидор
    )
[фрукты] => Array
    (
        [0] => апельсин
        [1] => мандарин
        [2] => черешня
    )
)
```

объединяю массивы следующим образом:

```
$basket = array_merge_recursive($first, $second);
```

в результате получаю:

```
Array
(
[овощи] => Array
    (
        [0] => огурец
        [1] => помидор
    )
[фрукты] => Array
    (
        [0] => апельсин
        [1] => мандарин
        [2] => апельсин
        [3] => мандарин
        [4] => черешня
    )
[рыба] => Array
    (
        [0] => налим
        [1] => сазан
        [2] => щука
        [3] => плотва
    )
)
```

Собственно вопрос: как удалит повторяющиеся значения? в данном примере это [2] => апельсин и [3] => мандарин.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [**array_unique()**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) и [**array_values()**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php):

```
$first = Array
(
    'овощи' => Array
    (
        'огурец',
    ),
    'фрукты' => Array
    (
        'апельсин',
        'мандарин'
    ),
    'рыба' => Array
    (
        'налим',
        'сазан',
        'щука',
        'плотва'
    )
);

$second = Array
(
    'овощи' => Array
    (
        'помидор'
    ),
    'фрукты' => Array
    (
        'апельсин',
        'мандарин',
        'черешня'
    )
);

$basket = array_merge_recursive($first, $second);
$basket = array_map('array_values', array_map('array_unique', $basket));

var_dump($basket);
```

---

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  'овощи' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'огурец' (length=12)
      1 => string 'помидор' (length=14)
  'фрукты' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'апельсин' (length=16)
      1 => string 'мандарин' (length=16)
      2 => string 'черешня' (length=14)
  'рыба' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'налим' (length=10)
      1 => string 'сазан' (length=10)
      2 => string 'щука' (length=8)
      3 => string 'плотва' (length=12)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает

Comment: @Иван если мой ответ решает вашу задачу, отметьте его галкой.